# Rollback Ruby Version on Windows

Tags: windows, ruby, version, windows-vista

How do you rollback from Ruby 1.9 to Ruby 1.8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "specific method to roll back". You'll want to run the uninstaller (if you used some kind of installation program) and reinstall Ruby 1.8.

You might want to save a list of RubyGems that you have installed, by typing `gem list` in a command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general method for rolling back to an earlier version.  T[he ruby version manager](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) however makes managing multiple ruby versions very easy.  I use it on os x but I'm sure it works just as well for windows.

Comment: Actually, RVM does not run on windows.